# Containing div is not containing a list

Tags: html, css

I have a list that I want contained within a header div:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the header div does not contain the menu div.

My understanding of divs is that div x containing div y will contain all of the elements within div y. But that is not happening.

Setting the height of the containing div to x pixels works only until you resize the browser. When the browser becomes small enough, the the li elements are no longer contained within the containing div. I want the li elements contained within the header no matter how small the browser is.

Here is my CSS code:

```
#header{
    background-color: orange;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; /*removing results in none of the menu items being contained */
}   
li{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Now you need to understand the `float` http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: So what do you want to happen when the window becomes to small? I dont understand the question. Explain what you want it to do. As you have set a height to the header it will leak out when its to small. Setting the height to auto will keep the element inside. If you want it to stay at the minimal width set `min-width`.

Comment: Ruddy - I want the menu items to be contained within the header no matter how small the window is made. I have edited my question to make that clear.

Comment: @AnthonyBartoli I added an answer that does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code will do. You should add `overflow:hidden;`

```
#header{
    background-color: orange;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: strongly not recommended method....this method `hide`s the problem, not solves it...`clearfix` is a better solution

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want then...

These is no need to use float for this. `display: inline;` is prefect for this sort of thing. Using the method you ticked as correct is not a good move.
[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/4hMJb/)

### HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#header{
    background-color: orange;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not set height for the outer container remove height for the element : #header

Example :

```
#header{
    background-color: orange;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
  //  height: 50px; /*removing results in none of the menu items being contained */
}

li{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style:none;
}
```

See the working example [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BalaVaradarajan/UXFx8/)